# Web Scraping news article and exporting to csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been learning the basics of python for the last month or so and while I am very adept at printing out 'hello world', I would like to learn some additional functionality. I have downloaded BeautifulSoup4 and am using Python2.7.  My goal is to be able to take an article from CNN or another news source and be able to scrap 4 things:
1) Link to the website
2) Date article published
3) title of article
4) Text of the article

I have searched other questions in stackoverflow and looked at other example code, but I am having problems applying it to what I want to do. Most of the examples I see are scraping the time of day or the weather. My main issue is that when I look at the sourcecode of a particular website I have a hard time knowing what tags I am supposed to be using.

So for example if I wanted to scrap the above 4 things from:
http://www.cnn.com/2013/10/29/us/florida-shooting-cell-phone-blocks-bullet/index.html?hpt=ju_c2

What would the code look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a proof of concept code to make your idea work, just to let you know, the BeautifulSoup4 is really powerful and it is absolutely enough for your first stage in scraping.

Also you need to read the terms of service of CNN to check out if the scraping is allowed or not. You can find the explanation for every single detail of the code below in BS4 documentation or you can start your career in stackoverflow to learn every detail from the community, like what I have done :) Good luck and enjoy it!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import urllib2
import re

def main():
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    url = 'http://www.cnn.com/2013/10/29/us/florida-shooting-cell-phone-blocks-bullet/index.html?hpt=ju_c2'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(url))
    #1) Link to the website 

    #2) Date article published 
    date = soup.find("div", {"class":"cnn_strytmstmp"}).text.encode('utf-8')
    #3) title of article 
    title = soup.find("div", {"id":"cnnContentContainer"}).find('h1').text.encode('utf-8')
    #4) Text of the article
    paragraphs = soup.find('div', {"class":"cnn_strycntntlft"}).find_all('p')
    text = " ".join([ paragraph.text.encode('utf-8') for paragraph in paragraphs])

    print url
    print date
    print title 
    print text

if __name__ == '__main__':   
     main()
```

The output looks like this:

```
http://www.cnn.com/2013/10/29/us/florida-shooting-cell-phone-blocks-bullet/index.html?hpt=ju_c2
updated 7:34 AM EDT, Tue October 29, 2013
Cell phone stops bullet aimed at Florida gas station clerk
(CNN) -- A gas station clerk's smartphone may... the TV station reported.
```

Meanwhile, a bit of philosophy from me on how we should locate elements: [link here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618135/beautifulsoup-exception-list-out-of-range/19620933#19620933)
And Selenium/Scrapy you might also encounter later..

Comment: B Mr. W. thank you for your answer. What is the 'utf-8'?

Comment: @intelligentlywrong utf-8 tell the python to interpret text using UTF-8 which is how the browser decode. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. Otherwise, sth.text will return unicode instead of string.

Comment: I am trying to run your code but I get the error as `No module named 'urllib2'`. I have Python 2.7 using Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do a few things:

- Download the webpage using `urllib` or `python-requests`
- Parse the page with `BeautifulSoup4` (`bs4`)
- Identify the portions of the webpage you want to parse, with Chrome(or other browser) via the Developer Tools ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and click on the text body of the article, which'll allow you to see the HTML elements you want to parse out. In this case, you can see that you want all the HTML elements with the class `cnn_storypgraphtxt` that you can select with `soup.find_all("p", class_="cnn_storypgraphtxt")`

I'm sure you'll be able to figure out the rest by yourself, as far as where the elements are that contain the dates and titles etc.

Answer (score 2):

You won't find the **URL of a page** *in* the page itself, but that's not a problem since you must have known the URL before you fetched the page.

Scraping is at its most powerful when it's **site-specific:** You need to examine the format of (say) the CNN site's pages, determine where they put the article date, find your way in the document hierarchy by examining the html source, and then design a way to extract it.

In a most general way you can at best recognize generic types of information: You can write a script that extracts all **dates** from a page (or as many as your criteria can match), but there's no general way to know which one represents the date of publication.  Similarly, extracting the **title** and **text** in a really general way is at best guesswork, since there are so many ways to embed this information in a web page (and so many other things the site could be mixing in with it).

Finally, don't forget that many sites (though not all) will send you a bare-bones html page and use **javascript** to populate it with content. Unless you use something like [webkit](http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/) to interpret the javascript before you try to scrape the page, your script will see something very different from what your browser shows you.